# Google GClientGeocoder geocoder function - how to pass extra parm(s)?

Tags: function, asynchronous, maps

I am using Google GClientGeocoder geocoder function.
Method getLocations seems to be a a Google asynchronous callback function.

I would like to update the record identified with "id" with points found in GLatLng,
However I can't figure out how to add id as a parameter to my getGeoCode function.

```
   function fnGetEncoding(address,id)
   {
  // Create new geocoding object
  geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();

  // Retrieve location information, pass it to getGeoCode()
  geocoder.getLocations(address, getGeoCode);  
   }

   function getGeoCode(response)
   {
  // Retrieve the object
  place = response.Placemark[0];

  // Retrieve the latitude and longitude
  point = new GLatLng(place.Point.coordinates[1],
        place.Point.coordinates[0]);

  $('#id_listing').append(response.name + point + '<br>');    

  // I would like to update the record identified with "id" with points found GLatLng

  // fnWriteGeocodesToFile(response.name, id , point)  



    }
```

Comment: Maybe you should to accept your previously questions before asking new?

Answer (score 0):

I think, it's quite simple:

```
function fnGetEncoding(address,id)
{
  // Create new geocoding object
  geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();

  // Retrieve location information, pass it to getGeoCode()

  geocoder.getLocations(address,
  **function(response,id){**
   getGeoCode(response,id);  
  **}**
}

function getGeoCode(response,id)
{
  // Retrieve the object
  place = response.Placemark[0];

  // Retrieve the latitude and longitude
  point = new GLatLng(place.Point.coordinates[1],
    place.Point.coordinates[0]);

  $('#id_listing').append(response.name + point + '<br>');    

  // I would like to update the record identified with "id" with points found GLatLng

  // fnWriteGeocodesToFile(response.name, id , point)  

}
```